# New SQL Server index not utilized in execution plan

Tags: sql-server, indexing, sql-server-2012, sql-execution-plan

I have recently taken on some of the Jr DBA functions for my company. We're running SQL Server 2012.

I created an index yesterday but the query optimizer doesn't seem to be wanting to use it. I can force the index with the query hint, however I want to ensure the other users in the system is going to benefit from this index as well

```
select count(*) 
from prospect p
join phone ph with (index([ix_phone_ProspectId])) 
     on ph.prospect_id = p.prospect_id
```

The above query runs about 3 seconds.

The below query runs for about a minute at which point I stop it

```
select count(*) 
from prospect p
join phone ph on ph.prospect_id = p.prospect_id
```

Any suggestions on how I can help the query optimizer look for this index and start utilizing it moving forward? (note, statistics have been updated since deploying the index)

Comment: This question is best suited for [dba.se]; please consider reading [this advice](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3034/asking-query-performance-questions) though.

Comment: Script the index and post it.

Comment: And also: show us the **table structure**, and tell us about the data in the table - how much of it, are there certain values that occur much more often than others?

Comment: What does the Query Plan show?  Does the query plan show any missing indexes?  But, as noted above this question is better suited for Database Administrators.

Comment: If we assume a 1:M relationship from Prospect to phone, are you not just counting rows in phone? Why join if you do not need to join?

Comment: Correct, there is a 1:M relationship  from prospect to phone. This is just a sample query that is going to reference these two tables since this correlation is made very frequently in our system.

Comment: The prospect table has roughtly 5m records, the phone table has 65m records (because in addition to the phones from prospects we also record phones from national DNC etc. to ensure our legal compliance is in).

Only about 4m of the phones are tied to a prospect

The index is written:
````
create index ix_phone_ProspectId on dbo.phone
(
 prospect_id asc
)
include (prospect_phone_status_id) 
where (prospect_id is not null)
````

Answer (score 0):

You could create a view, put the index hint in there and point users to that view.

```
CREATE TABLE X(i int PRIMARY KEY);
CREATE INDEX xx ON X(i)
GO

CREATE VIEW dbo.vwX WITH SCHEMABINDING AS
select xxx = count(*) 
from dbo.X p with (index(xx))
```

You can also lose the current new index and create an indexed view then point users to that.

```
ALTER VIEW dbo.vwX WITH SCHEMABINDING AS
select xxx = count_big(*) 
from dbo.X p

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX vwXX ON dbo.vwX(xxx);
```

Note that you can't use an index hint with an indexed view unless its an in-memory table.